# python selenium clearing cache and cookies

Tags: python, selenium, caching, cookies

I'm trying to clear the cache and cookies in my firefox browser but I can't get it to work. I have searched it up and i'm only getting solutions for java and C#. How do I clear the cache and cookies in Python?

selenium version: 3.6.0

platform: python

python version: 2.7.8

webdriver: geckodriver

browser platform: Firefox

Comment: Close the webdriver and open it again

Answer (score 59):

For cookies use `delete_all_cookies()` function

> driver.delete_all_cookies()

for cache create profile

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.cache.disk.enable", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.cache.memory.enable", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.cache.offline.enable", False)
profile.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False) 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Comment: Is there any way to clear cookies without creating a new instance of a web driver?